# Propiedad transition-delay css

Tags: html, css, css3

Estoy tratando de resolver un problema bastante simple con transition css, 
el problema es que no se que estoy haciendo mal a la hora de asignarle los valores a transition-delay, me arroja error de que los valores son son los esperados, cabe aclarar que es un ejercicio online, adjunto la imagen de la pagina la cual arroja el error(el editor de codigo que estoy usando lo corre sin ningun problema, el error es con la pagina de la imagen) y el codigo por si quieren probarlo.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqjqL.png

```css
div {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 40px auto;
  border: 5px solid black;
}

#elemento:hover {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 400px;
}

#elemento {
  transition-property: border-radius, background-color, width;
  transition-duration: 2s, 0.5s, 1s;
  transition-delay: 0s, 3s, 3.5s;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Transform</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <style>

  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Transformaciones</h1>

  <div id="elemento">elemento</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir aquí el código que tienes actualmente para poder ver exactamente cual es el problema?

Comment: edite la pregunta, para que se entienda mejor.

Comment: Entiendo que estas haciendo algún cursillo de CSS? Bueno, en la imagen que has puesto pone que el delay se calcula en base a la duración de las propiedades anteriores. Lo que has puesto es: la duración es: `2s, 0.5s, 1s` y el delay es: `0s,3s,4s`. A mi punto de ver debería de ser `0s,2s,2.5s`. 2 segundos de la 1º propiedad. 0.5 segundos de la 2º propiedad